# How often should the DHE p and g factors be recycled?

Tags: tls, diffie-hellman

I've been asked to enable DHE in our SMTP product. I'm stuck on this question:

How often should the product regenerate its DHE *p* and *g* parameters?

I've seen some implementations that use a cron job to regenerate *p* and *g* once per day; others (e.g., Postfix) set *p* and *g* as source code constants. The most common approach seems to be once at install time.

If I understand it correctly, even if *p* and *g* are known to an attacker, recovering the encryption key means solving the discrete logarithm problem. From that I would infer that generating *p* and *g* at install time is more than adequate. But I also saw media reports about a year ago suggesting that the discrete logarithm problem might be solved by the end of the decade; that would suggest regenerating *p* and *g* regularly might be prudent.

Answer (score 2):

So `p` is the modulus, and `g` is the generator.  You are absolutely right.  `p` and `g` are publicly known values, and the [discrete log problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) needs to be solved to break the Diffie-Hellman exchange.

### Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman

The whole point of Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman is to provide for Perfect Forward Secrecy (PFS).  Here's an answer I already wrote up on [DHE and PFS](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/65808/52676) for more information.

- [Generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group):  These are generally fairly small.  A protocol like SSH will allow you to exchange the group [(RFC4419)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4419.txt), but there are two standard values used for SSH; 2 and 5.  If you like math stuff, here's an [explanation on generators in DH.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/831)
- Moduli:  A modulus for DH is a large prime

These parameters need to be generated only once by the server for each size that you're looking to support.  I would use OpenSSL's functionality as it's described in their wiki.

Here's [OpenSSL's Wiki on DH Parameters](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie-Hellman_parameters).

[This article](http://blog.ivanristic.com/2013/06/ssl-labs-deploying-forward-secrecy.html) linked to in that wiki gives good information on PFS, and configuring your SSL/TLS enabled server to use it.  You need to make sure your server has a version that supports it, and put the PFS cipher suites (DHE and ECDHE) at the top of your list.

Comment: Ah ha, thank you for the detailed answer and for clearing up my mental block. I realize now I got myself wrapped around the axle thinking of *p* and *g* as if they needed to be kept secret, like a private key. But of course that would defeat the whole purpose of DHE.

Comment: @Carl Do use p at least 1024 bits and preferably 2048; dlog attacks seem to fairly closely follow factoring/RSA which has reached nearly 800. Also I advise against putting params in source (as the wiki examples do); even though we don't expect to need to replace them, making it unnecessarily difficult to do so is tempting fate.

Comment: Thanks, all. The implementation was easier that I expected; I just call dhparam from the same startup script that generates the product's SSH keys.

PCI requires at least 1024 bits. There is a lively discussion in IETF TLS WG regarding minimum DHE parameter group size; I'll be following their recommendations.