# Find the Encryption Key (used for network encryption) assuming a Trust Chain is being used on Windows?

Tags: tls, certificates, windows

If I double click on a `.crt` file, in Windows, I'm presented with three tabs `General`, `Details`, and `Certification Path`.  I'm aware that the `Certification Path` tells you the details of which root and intervening CAs as well as your own certificate, but how do you find [the encryption key used for network encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/105828/6103)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean what Microsoft calls *Your Public Key Used for Encryption* [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376502).

And in that case you're simply looking for the `Public key` field.

[image: Screenshot of Windows 10 dialog for "example.org" certificate]